# How to get the value returned by break in while loop

Tags: ruby, break

Here is the sample code that returns a argument when it breaks the loop,

```
i=10
while true
   i += 1
   break i if i % 7 == 0
end
```

Can someone tell me how to get what value it returns, but is obvious the value is `i` (i.e 14). I want, how do I get the value without using the `i` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value passed to `break` becomes the value of the `while` loop expression.

```
i=10
result = while true
           i += 1
           break i if i % 7 == 0
         end
puts result # 14
```